# Confused between Angular 1+ versions?

Tags: angular

I have started learning Angular and found that the structure of directories is different between them. Let's assume I'm using Angular 2.

Project 1 
sample component has this line:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

but in some it's replaced by

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Also, some have `component.ts` file in `project/app/component.ts` and in some projects, the structure is like `project/src/app.component.ts`.

There are many more changes like this. What exactly is going on?

Comment: `import { Component } from '@angular/core'` is the right syntax here. `@angular/core` is actually one of the main packages required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

This was used in the earlier versions of Angular when it was introduced back in 2014. Hence it says as angular2.

With the evolution of angular (different versions), Angular8 is the latest. It is imported as `import { Component } from '@angular/core';`.

You need to follow the latest version, so the later one is the correct one.

In order to see what has been changed over the period of time, you can read [`the changelog`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

This way of import was used in the earlier release of the Angular (some call it Angular2, but it's just Angular).

But later on as the framework got stable they renamed it to @angular/core. So currently you have the import statement as below:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
```

The same goes with the folder structure.

Earlier it was `project/app/component.ts` but now it goes `project/app/app.component.ts`.

If you are still confused then you may want to create a sample angular application and see it yourself. You can create a sample application by executing the command `ng new my-app`, provided you have installed all the dependencies and setup the environment.

Comment: Thank u so much  Akash:)

Comment: Your welcome. Hope my answer helped you. P.S. If it really did, could you mark it as accepted answer?